# Не работают аргументы переданные в функцию JS DataTables

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatable, laravel7

Почему не подключается, а точнее не срабатывает `Responsive DataTables` в `Laravel 7`
Подключаю плагин и расширение таким образом (Интеграция [AdminLTE 3](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE))

```
'plugins' => [
    [
        'name' => 'Datatables',
        'active' => false,
        'files' => [
            [
                'type'     => 'js',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/Foundation-6.4.3/js/foundation.min.js',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'js',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'js',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.20/js/dataTables.foundation.min.js',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'js',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/Responsive-2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'js',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/Responsive-2.2.3/js/responsive.foundation.min.js',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'js',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/Responsive-2.2.3/js/responsive.foundation.min.js',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'css',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/Foundation-6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'css',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.20/css/dataTables.foundation.min.css',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'css',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/Responsive-2.2.3/css/responsive.foundation.min.css',
            ],
            [
                'type'     => 'css',
                'asset'    => true,
                'location' => 'vendor/datatables/Select-1.3.1/css/select.foundation.min.css',
            ],
        ],
    ]...
]
```

На самой странице где нужен плагин `@section('plugins.Datatables', true)` Все стили и скрипты подгружаются в правильном порядке 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-request').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
});
```

Таблица преобразовывается в таблицу DataTable, но "адаптация" не подключается. И вообще никакие аргументы переданные в функцию `DataTable` не работают, например

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-request').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        select: true
    });
});
```

В данном случае ни Select, ни Responsive не подключаются к таблице.
В чем может быть дело? Если я просто создаю HTML страницу и все вот так подключаю, то все работает